# SystemJS with Polymer + Elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, aurelia, jspm, systemjs

In a *SystemJS*+*JSPM* managed project, how can I use *Polymer*'s elements?

I've used `jspm install github:Polymer/polymer` to install *Polymer*, and also `jspm install github:PolymerElements/iron-elements` to install *iron-elements*.

There seems to be multiple issues with this:

First one, for example that in the iron-elements.html file, the imports are going to the wrong paths: `<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">` while the *Polymer* directory is actually named with it's version (as usual with *JSPM*), so the the actual import should be `<link rel="import" href="../polymer@1.0.5/polymer.html">` in my case.

Second, while importing the *Polymer* files, it seems a bit blunt in a *SystemJS* environment to just place it inside index.html like that, including the version path:

```
<link rel="import" href="jspm_packages/bower/Polymer/polymer@1.0.5/polymer.html" />
```

Is there a better way have these html imports in *SystemJS*?

Third, since *Polymer*'s download options are either via manual download using their "cart" like option or in *Bower*, if I try to fetch *iron-elements* or *paper-elements* via JSPM's `github:` repository or `bower:`, it does not download their dependencies, and even if I add the dependencies manually, their `import` paths would still be wrong because of the version naming of *JSPM*.

According to this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jspm-io/YcApuhKWdUU) in *JSPM*'s *google group*, the issue

> is that Polymer assumes Bower

Which kind of forces me to ditch either *SystemJS* or *Polymer* which I really don't want to do.

However, in a different [discussion](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/eisenbergeffect/aurelia_qa) (of *Aurelia* framework), Rob Eisenberg mentions a possibility of using Polymer with *Aurelia*:

> You should be able to use Polymer's Paper elements. To do that you
>   would include the Polymer framework in your page prior to Aurelia.

As far as I've learned, *Aurelia* is using *JSPM*, so can it be done?

A possible solution would be to switch to *RequireJS*, then I can just use *Bower* to add *Polymer*'s stuff, but I would really like to use *SystemJS*, and I'm not sure if it will work with *Aurelia*.
Also, I could keep using *SystemJS* and *JSPM*, and also use *Bower* just for *Polymer* stuff.

---

### Update

Until a better answer is found, a temporary solution is to use both *JSPM* and *Bower*, where *Bower* is used only for *Polymer*.

Comment: Still have to try it myself, but this blog contains a number of articles on NPM, Bower and Polymer: http://shellmonger.com/2015/04/15/comparing-web-components-part-2-polymer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you solved your problem but I've found a way to install polymer and its components through jspm.

Referring to issue https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1133, follow the next steps:

```
npm install jspm-bower-endpoint
jspm registry create bower jspm-bower-endpoint
```

With this, you will be able to install bower packages through jspm, just like you can do jspm install nom:, you will be able to do the same with bower.

Now, install Polymer and Paper-elements (or any other collection).

```
jspm install bower:polymer
jspm install bower:PolymerElements/paper-elements
```

In this last step, I had a small problem with packaging version that I couldn't solve through jspm. So just go to jspm_packages/bower/PolymerElements/paper-elements@version and run

```
bower install
```

This last step will install all the components for paper-elements.

Now, just attach the needed element to your html template through:

```
<link rel="import" href="jspm_packages/bower/PolymerElements/paper-elements@version/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Hope you can find this useful!

Comment: Still kinda tricky way, not very different from what I did myself, but it works, so in the meantime it's fine. :-)

Comment: @Alex I don't see how this is a solution. You are suggesting that we install ALL of paper-elements (when all I would want is maybe one component). Unfortunately, installing one component doesn't work because the version number in the URL gets in the way. Also, in JSPM 0.16.31, it still doesn't install it's deps.